# Получение заголовков окон

Tags: delphi, многопоточность, delphi-7, windows-xp, служба

Пишу службу на Delphi7. В ней несколько потоков. Один из них ловит заголовки окон(перепробовал уже множество способов). На форме всё
работает отлично(WindowsForm). Но в службе нет...

1. Служба не циклится в потоке While not NewThread3.Terminated do
2. Не ловятся заголовки(либо в 1 из 10 случаев, ловлю заголовок Delphi).

Помогите понять почему.

```
   function EnumWindowsProc(wHandle: HWND; lParam: Integer): BOOL; stdcall;
    var
      Title: array[0..255] of char;
    begin
      GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255);
      if IsWindowVisible(wHandle)
      and (GetWindow(wHandle, gw_Owner) = 0)
      and (GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255) <> 0) then
        MSServisPC.WriteCaption(string(Title)); //Прецедура записи в бд
      Result := True;
    end;

procedure TNewThread3.WriteHandle;
begin
While not NewThread3.Terminated do
  begin
    EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, integer(NewThread3));
    sleep(WaitHandleWrite);
  end;
end;

procedure TNewThread3.Execute;
begin
try
  Success3:=CoInitialize(nil);
    try
      WriteHandle;
    finally
      case Success3 of
        S_OK, S_FALSE: CoUninitialize;
      end;
    end;
  except on E:Exception do
    MSServisPC.AddLog(DateTimeToStr(Now) + ': Îøèáêà ïðè ñîçäàíèè ïîòîêà ¹3. ' + E.Classname + ':' + E.Message, 'MSServicePCError.txt');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Начиная с Windows Vista сервис не имеет доступа к десктопу. Поэтому не может ничего отловить. UPD: не обратил внимания на тег Windows-XP. Тогда дополнение: флаг Interactive для сервиса выставлен?

Comment: На ПК, на котором пишу стоит (w7 x64). Если выводить в ListBox по кнопке. То всё работает.

Comment: Тогда еще раз внимательно перечитайте мой комментарий. Для версий Windows от Vista и выше **в сервисе** вы не получите желаемое. Никак.

Comment: Да но winXP то же не работает.

Comment: И еще раз перечитайте мой комментарий. У сервиса свойство Interactive выставлено?

Comment: Сейчас включу и проверю. Но тут еще 1 проблемка.

Comment: While not NewThread3.Terminated do цикл не крутится. То есть он 1 раз заходит и всё.

Comment: `NewThread3` - это что за переменная? В представленном коде не видно ее объявления и как она заполняется. А именно в этом и кроется проблема. Судя по всему, ее можно спокойно убрать, оставив только `while not terminated do`

Comment: Да, вы правы. Служба работает на winXP. Но есть машина(1) на win7...

Comment: Но почему тогда если использовать GetWindowText(wHandle, Title, 255); в цикле, я могу получить на win7, а на winXP нет?! Или дело в этом флаге Interactive.

Answer (score 1):

В свойствах сервиса обратите внимание на вкладку "Log On", может быть поможет, если вы будете логиниться под той же учетной записью, что и работаете (с галочкой Интерактивность)?

По умолчанию служба запускается от имени Система, а вы же понимаете, что один пользователь не может посмотреть, что делается у другого пользователя (в частности, какие окна открыты).

Как вариант, запускать некую proxy-программу от имени пользователя, которая будет собирать нужную информацию и по TCP передавать сервису.